# Border on Fonts in IE using text-shadow

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm using following in CSS to outline my fonts with some border but this doesn't work in IE, is there any possibility, I can do the similar stuff so that this works in IE. At present, this works well in Chrome, FF, Safari.

```
.ItemPrice { 
     font-size: 40px; 
     color: #E8C61E; 
     -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #B2412F; 
     text-shadow: -1px 0 #B2412F, 0 1px #B2412F, 1px 0 #B2412F, 0 -1px #B2412F; 
 }
```

As these are prices coming out dynamically, I can't use images. If anyone could help me, it would be great.

Adding more description to it as people marked it duplicate question.

1. I know that I can use Filter to create the shadow but that doesn't give a border like feel to the font.
2. If we play with multiple dropShadow Filters to create Border, the font gets cut off from the corners, which again doesn't look good.
3. There are JS plugins available for creating the Fonts with border but as the Price which I need to display has to be displayed multiple times on the same page so it makes it very slow using those JS plugins.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IE doesn't support text-shadow in versions lower than 10, but it's long supported a proprietary analog.

Comment: For such a small effect is it worth the hassle of trying to force it to work in IE? It will function fine without it.

Comment: Only reason being, there are some propriety softwares which uses IE as some web support (back end kind of not sure), hence it has to be supported there.

Answer (score 0):

you could make multiple text shadows with the filter:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='white') progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=1,offY=1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=-1,offY=1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=1,offY=-1) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#ffffff,offX=-1,offY=-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into this, it works similar to css3 PIE but has some text shadow functionality. I have never used this specific one but it may be worth a shot.

http://www.fetchak.com/ie-css3/